# Is multiple inheritance acceptable for nodes in a tree?

Tags: c++

I was wondering:

With a tree, the root can have multiple children and no id. All nodes (except the root) have an id and the leaf nodes can not have children. It is fixed what type must be used for each depth. So the leaves are always of the same type and so are the parents of the leaves.

Since the root and the nodes can have children and only the nodes have an id I was wondering if the following use of multiple inheritance is acceptable:

```
class NodeWithId
{
    private:
        std::string m_id;
};

template<typename T>
class NodeWithChildren
{
    private:
        std::vector<T> m_nodes;
};

class Network: public NodeWithChildren<Subnet>
{
};

class Subnet: public NodeWithChildren<Machine>, 
                     public NodeWithId
{
};

class Machine: public NodeWithChildren<Application>, 
               public NodeWithId
{
};

class Application: public NodeWithId
{
};
```

Or is there a better way to implement this?

edit:

- removed virtual
- changed classnames

Comment: Why are you using virtual inheritance? There is no shared base class in any of the inheritance paths.

Comment: I'd use a single class for all kinds of nodes and just use a dummy id in the root and empty child vectors in the leafs

Comment: I agree with Manuel - use an ID of -1 or 0 or some other reserved value for the root, and simplify your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is there a better way to implement this?

IMHO, your design creates classes for stuff that are best treated as object instances. At a class level I do not see the need to differentiate between Level1 nodes and Level2 nodes.

Use a design that is simple. Ask yourself, if this design has any potential benefits or not than the naive approach of having a single `Node` class and creating a tree structure out of `Node` instances (which you create at runtime).

Comment: type safety? If everything in the tree is a Node then you have to dynamically check the type of each Node.

Comment: @rve: Why do you need to check the type of a `Node`? Some idea about the operations/algorithms you plan to execute on your tree may be helpful here.

Comment: I want to use it to describe a system, for example PC's in a network (the real scenario is similar but more complex). So, the root node is just the root. The children of the root are Subnets, the children of the Subnets are Machines, the children of the Machines are Applications and are the leaves.
I want to prevent adding Applications to the root for instance. And If I fetch the children of a Machine I want to be sure (without dynamic type checking) they are Applications.

Comment: @rve: The inheritance bit is not clear among say, a `Machine` and a `Subnet`. It appears to me that a `Node` is more of an implementation detail (yes, you guessed right, thinking of the pipl-idiom here!).Dynamic type checking -- again rethink. Also remember, virtual functions often ease the pain of type-checks.

Comment: Do you mean the entire tree consists of Node objects and those Node objects then reference/contain some other class like Machine, Subnet etc?

Comment: @rye: Rather, the other way round.

Comment: This answer helped me rethink my design and doing it this way certainly made it clearer. That is why I accepted this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with single inheritance:

```
class NodeWithId
{
    private:
        std::string m_id;
};

template<typename T>
class NodeWithChildren : public NodeWithId
{
    private:
        std::vector<T> m_nodes;
};

class Root: public NodeWithChildren<Level1Node>
{
};

class Level1Node: public NodeWithChildren<Level2Node>
{
};

class Level2Node: public NodeWithChildren<LeafNode>
{
};

class LeafNode: public NodeWithId
{
};
```

You would only need multiple inheritance in the case that you can have a NodeWithChildren that DOESN'T have an ID. In your design above every NodeWithChildren also has a NodeWithId so you may as well derive NodeWithChildren from NodeWithId and totally bypass any potential multiple inheritance problems.

Seems like a "better" design to me ...

Comment: But then I have to give the root a dummy id.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need for virtual inheritance, based on the sample code you posted, there is no '[dreaded diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)'

But I don't really get your design at all, there's no common base class for anything representing your tree, why are you using inheritance at all? It looks like everything could be achieved using composition.

Is this simply a slimmed down version of your hierarchy made for this question?

Comment: Well, some nodes can have children and the code for managing this list of children is something which can be in a base class because it will be the same for all nodes (except for the leave nodes). 

Yes, you are right about the virtual inheritance.

Can you give an example on how to do this by composition ?

Answer (score -1):

Your performance will be unbearable, and your code unbelievably convoluted.

First you use a template, which has a vector in it, for each node.

The vector alone will dramatically slow things. Having to cast things would make your traversal code very very slow, and the code itself would be hard to comprehend for anyone else.

Also, since you have different classes, how is the vector able to deal with that? Answer, it can't. That means it has to be a vector of pointers to a base class. Then you have to figure out what the proper type is at runtime to get any use out of them.

If this added some sort of benefit then it might be worth it for some uses, but it's really the opposite of what you want from a structure like a tree, which should be as simple as possible to use and comprehend and have as few memory allocations as possible and ideally good performance.